# Sort based on percentage value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, jqgrid

I have a "true percentage value" which is calculated using :

```
true% = true_answers/total_answers
```

where total_answers is the SUM of total_correct_answers and total_incorrect_answers. I am using the following query to fetch the TRUE and FALSE answers.

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(true_answer = 1, 1, 0)) AS total_correct_answers, 
SUM(IF(correct_answer != 1, 1, 0)) AS total_incorrect_answers FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

I calculate the total_answers and true_percentage value using PHP using the total_correct_answers and total_incorrect_answers and displaying these values in jqgrid. Now I need to sort the listing based on the "true%" value. How this can be done ? I tried

```
ORDER BY SUM(IF(correct_answer = 1, 1, 0))/SUM(IF(correct_answer != 1,1,0))+SUM(IF(correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) asc
```

But this is sorting the grid incorrectly. How can this be done ?

Comment: i think in the base query you can order by total_correct_answer desc where you will get the highest correct answer first which sorts for you by default in highest correct answers order then you can find out % using php

Comment: But this is not working fine. It will sort the results incorrectly.